# unable to connect to my nexus 10 with android 4.4 and cyanogenmod with a remote desktop manager

Tags: remote-control, remote-access, firewall, selinux

Hello android users and developers.

I would like to give a developer temporary access to my tablet so he can help me solve a problem. On the tablet is running android 4.4 + cyanogen mod 11. I have installed the no-ip client for android and a tool called "airdroid" and I have also configured an ssh account.

I'm not able to connect to the tablet using the domain name (marietto2008.no-ip.org) that I have associated to the internal IP number (192.168.254.1). This is what happens when I try to ping the internal IP number and the domain name associated :

```
root@localhost:/home/marietto# ping 192.168.254.1

PING 192.168.254.1 (192.168.254.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.254.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=435 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.254.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=559 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.254.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=582 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.254.1: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=403 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.254.1: icmp_req=5 ttl=64 time=18.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.254.1: icmp_req=6 ttl=64 time=141 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.254.1: icmp_req=7 ttl=64 time=470 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.254.1: icmp_req=8 ttl=64 time=10.8 ms

    [1]+  Stopped                 ping 192.168.254.1

root@localhost:/home/marietto# ping marietto2008.no-ip.org

PING marietto2008.no-ip.org (external IP number) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

it hangs !

I can connect to the tablet using this address that I have received when I have installed airdroid :

http://web.airdroid.com/ or http://192.168.254.1:8888

but I can't connect to it using this way :

http://marietto2008.no-ip.org:8888

also,I can connect remotely with the tablet using the ssh account at this address :

```
192.168.254.1:46143
```

but not using the domain name :

```
marietto2008.no-ip.org:46143
```

I've also configured the port triggers on the router configuration panel :

[image: router port triggers]

Comment: How's your device connected to the internet: WiFi or mobile data? If WiFi, there's a router in between. Did you setup corresponding NAT rules so the device can be reached from the "outer world"?

Comment: The tablet is connected to internet with the Wi-FI : I've configured the port triggers on the router configuration panel. check the picture.

Comment: You might need another rule in the port forwarding: port 22 UDP. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes. done it. but it does not work : root@localhost:/home/marietto# ping marietto2008.no-ip.org
PING marietto2008.no-ip.org (5.133.59.11) 56(84) bytes of data ---> it does not ping and when i try to login into the ssh account,it hangs and then it says : connection time out.

Comment: That has nothing to do with `ping` (AFAIK `ping` uses [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol); not sure how to tell the router where to put that). As for the SSH login: can you check your router log? Does it tell anything?

Comment: where can I found the log ? I'm using putty as ssh client and I can't see logs inside the wimax router control panel.

Comment: I cannot tell, I don't know the router. You could also [check the Android device's logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) for hints – though it rather seems the device is not even reached.